# HTML5 tags like(autofocus,required,type="email" do not work in IE9

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm using the html 5 tags like header,section,nav,article,autofocus,required, input type="email" and pattern.

i noticed that autofocus,type="email" and pattern do not work and i already use eric css reset and

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: btw, the only thing the html5shiv does is allow HTML5 tags to work in IE. If you try to use an 'unrecognized' tag like `header`, `footer`, or `aside` in IE without the shiv, IE doesn't render the tag at all (and missing elements often make a page look real messy real fast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the browser compatibility here : http://www.html5test.com 
Chrome supports the most features of HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

IE9 is an incompetent browser and this, among a multitude of other things, does not work in IE9. http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs.html

Comment: wew, so there is no other way to fix this? thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

I recently found a great library called [Webshims Lib](http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/index.html). The library works in concert with [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to determine what capabilities a browser has, and then polyfills the missing features.

The [forms portion of the library](http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/demos/webforms.html) is just freaking beautiful, and should meet your needs nicely. It handles a majority of the new HTML5 form features in browsers that don't already have support (like IE9).

I'd highly recommend giving it a try.